# in makefile, create an empty file if file not exists

Tags: linux, makefile

in makefile i am using an awk script to do some text manipulation

```
$(phony xyz):
   awk 'some script' file1 file2 > output;
```

while doing this if any of the file1 or file2 is missing, it will give an error. so i am thinking of adding an empty file if the file is already not existed.
like given below

```
$(phony xyz):
   test -e file1 || echo "" > file1;
   test -e file2 || echo "" > file2;
   awk 'some script' file1 file2 > output;
```

but this is not working.
**Ex**: if file1 is not there the error says file file1 not exists and then it is creating an empty file "file1" and for file2 without any error it simply emptying the file, so at the end both files becomes empty.

Comment: Are you sure you pasted the lines exactly from the Makefile? It should work (but using `touch` might be simpler).

Comment: @choroba : yes. that is the code i am using

Answer (score 3):

Why not adding these files as prerequisites and adding a rule to build them if they are missing?

```
$(phony xyz): file1 file2
   awk 'some script' file1 file2 > output;

file1 file2:
   touch $@
```

Comment: the same is not working if the files are taken from different directories  
       `$(phony xyz): dir1/file1 dir2/file2`  
              `awk 'some script' dir1/file1 dir2/file2 > output;`

       `dir1/file1 dir2/file2:`
             `touch $@`

Comment: @connectivitycable: Welcome on Stackoverflow. "Not working" is a very limited error message. What do you mean by "not working"? And, by the way, may I suggest that you visit the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to better understand how to optimize your chances of getting useful help?

Comment: @Renaud - You are being recruited for the [Stack Overflow Close Vote Room (SOCVR)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers). Information on the room is located at [SOCVR FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq). The room focuses on questions that need extra attention like crap magnets. It is a place where folks work at greater efficiency than the queues. I think you would be a good fit.